# What does it mean to import CSS into a TypeScript program?

Tags: typescript

If I create a TypeScript project in StackBlitz, the default content I get has a `style.css` file and an `index.ts` file that "imports" that CSS file(!) like this:

```
// Import stylesheets
import './style.css';
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-pfhuht)

What on earth does that mean?

Comment: Are you using WebPack?  Your CSS would be compiled as a module.

Comment: It's a babel / webpack thing. See [`css-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader)

Comment: @p.s.w.g: would you care to turn that into an answer?